# Memory details of a process

Tags: linux, memory-management, process

How can I get the memory details for a process running on linux?
I need to find out specific details like stack size, heap size of a process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find everything about your process in the `/proc/PID` directory. Especially in the `smaps` file where you will find the stack and heap size currently used.

[Documentation here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu: Grep returns only useful information
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'

For windows:
There is no grep in Windows, instead, we use findstr.
C:>java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"

The -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags is used to print out the values that modified by VM only